# How to handle status code 429 and avoid race condition in parallel requests?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have a problem with parallel requests to external API. Sometimes I get status code 429 from the server. In my scenario, multiple requests can get 429 at the same time

Here's the pseudocode:

```
const urls = ['https://example1', 'https://example2', 'https://example3']

const fetchData = async (url) => {
   const response = await fetch(url,  proxy=proxy)
   if (response.status === 429) {  
       // It can be that several requests got 429 at the same time, and all                                      
      // tasks are trying to change the proxy, when it is needed only once
     await changeProxy()
   }
   return response
}

Promise.all(urls.map(async (url) => {
  const response = await fetchData(url)
  ...
}));
```

I want only one of them to change proxy to avoid conflict. How can I implement this behavior?

Comment: Just remember in a simple boolean flag whether you already changed the proxy or not, then don't do it again?